# QProcess::startDetached shell is killed when the parent died if the parent is a systemd service

Tags: qt, qprocess

I'm using Qt 5.12.5 crosscompiled for pi4 and QProcess::startDetached is not working if I start my Qt programm as systemd service, meanwhile works as expected if it starts from shell.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, QT works as expected; it's systemd that works too well and closes the entire (hidden) process tree.

Take a look at the systemd service killmode configuration; you could also try to forcibly detach the spawned process from the tree.